# How to bind MVC API parameters in a JSONP Get?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, web-api-contrib

I created a VS 2012 MVC API project from scratch, loaded the Nuget "WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp", added a route, the formatter, and tried to send parameters as serialized JSON as a JSONP request.  How do I identify or access these parameters in the controller?

WebApiConfig:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{format}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, 
        format = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
config.Formatters.Insert(0, new JsonpMediaTypeFormatter());
```

Api Method:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/api/Values',
    data: JSON.stringify({ "message": "\"Hello World\"" }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (json) {
        console.dir(json.sites);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
});
```

I've tried modifying the Api method to include:

```
Get( [FromUri] string value)
Get( [FromBody] string value)
Get( CustomClass stuff)
Get( [FromUri] CustomClass stuff)
Get( [FromBody] CustomClass stuff)
```

Where CustomClass is defined as:

```
public class CustomClass
{
    public string message { get; set; }
}
```

So far, none of these produce anything but null for the parameters.  How should I wire up these parameters from the object posted in the querystring?

EDIT:

I can trick it by modifying the JQuery ajax to be:

```
data: {"value":JSON.stringify({ "message": "\"Hello World\"" })}
```

for which I can de-stringify the `[FromUri] string value` and get my strongly typed object.

Still, I'm expecting the data binder to de-serialize parameters in to strongly typed objects.  What technique makes this happen?

Comment: Currently, not very sure with exact solution but try changing the API parameter name to Id. i.e     Get( [FromUri] string id).. See, if it works. May sound out of context, but just give a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a `GET` request and in case of `GET` request there is no *body* only the URI. All the data you provide for the `$.ajax()` call will be put into URI, for example your EDIT version will generate URI like this:

```
.../api/Values?value=%7B%22message%22%3A%22%5C%22Hello%20World%5C%22%22%7D
```

(notice that the JSON will be also URL encoded).

Now the URI parameters in Web API are being bind with use of `ModelBinderParameterBinding`, which means that Web API will not use any `MediaTypeFormatter` (which outputs complex types), but a `ModelBinder`/`ValueProvider` (which in this case will output a simple type - string).

You can approach your scenario by implementing custom `ModelBinder` (remember to use proper classes and interfaces from ASP.NET Web API namespaces not ASP.NET MVC ones):

```
public class JsonModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (valueProviderResult == null)
            return false;

        bindingContext.Model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(valueProviderResult.AttemptedValue, bindingContext.ModelType);

        return true;
    }
}

public class JsonModelBinderProvider : ModelBinderProvider
{
    public override IModelBinder GetBinder(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        return new JsonModelBinder();
    }
}
```

And attaching it to your parameter with `ModelBinderAttribute`:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Get([ModelBinder(typeof(JsonModelBinderProvider))]CustomClass value)
{
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

You can find more details regarding the subject here:

- [Designing Evolvable Web APIs with ASP.NET - Chapter 8. Formatters and Model Binding](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449337711/ch_formatters_and_model_binding.html)